# Data Shift problem for Q6 & Q7 (starting from Q0) while using the 4094 I.C with a Micro-controller

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit

Currently I am using a PIC micro-controller with a 4094 IC but when I *WANT* to shift data to Q6 or Q7 it shifts it on Q0 & Q1 and when I shift it to Q0 & Q1 it turns on Q6 & Q7. So I do not have problems operating the output I want but why is this happening?

Below are the codes:

```
    void ShiftData(unsigned char Data)
{
        unsigned char i;
//        OUTEN=1;
        LED_A = 0;  //STROBE = 0;
        LED_C = 0;  //DISPCLK = 0;

        LED_B = 0;  //DISPDATA = 0;

        for(i = 0;i < 8;i++)
            {
                if(Data & 0x01) 
                   LED_B = 1;   //DISPDATA = 1;
                else 
                   LED_B = 0;   //DISPDATA = 0;

                LED_C = 1;  //DISPCLK = 1; 
                NOP(); 
                NOP(); 
                NOP(); 
                NOP(); 
                NOP(); 
                NOP(); 
                NOP(); 
                NOP(); 
                LED_C = 0;  //DISPCLK = 0;
                Data = Data >> 1;
            }

        LED_A = 1;  //STROBE = 1;
        NOP(); 
        NOP(); 
        NOP(); 
        NOP(); 
        NOP(); 
        NOP(); 
        NOP(); 
        NOP(); 

        LED_A = 0;  //STROBE = 0;
//      OUTEN=0;
}
```

What I perform is:

```
Reg_Data = 0x00;
Reg_Data |= (1 << 1);
ShiftData(Reg_Data);
```

This should turn Q1 high but it turns Q6 high.

Alternately:

```
Reg_Data = 0x00;
Reg_Data |= (1 << 0);
ShiftData(Reg_Data);
```

This action turns Q0 High rather than Q7.

Help would greatly be appreciated!

Link to 4094 I.C:
https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/HEF4094B.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is the difference between MSB first and LSB first serial.

The HEF4094 **expects** the data to be shifted in **MSB first** - that is bit 7 is the first data bit sent to it.

However your code is shifting data out LSB first. Notice that `Data & 0x01` extracts the LSB, and `Data = Data >> 1;` shifts the next LSB down to be sent.

To convert your code to MSB first, it's a simple task of changing those two lines to `Data & 0x80` (extract MSB) and `Data = Data << 1;` (shift next MSB up).